# Missing environment parameter in shell script

Tags: macos, shell, gulp, gruntjs

I have problem to launch the following shell script. I

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Missing environment parameter"
    exit 1
fi

 
environment=$1
npm=/opt/plesk/node/8/bin/npm
gulp=/opt/plesk/node/8/bin/gulp
grunt=/opt/plesk/node/8/bin/grunt
composer=/usr/bin/composer

home=$(pwd)
logs=${home}/logs
echo "home dir: ${home}" 
echo "logs dir: ${logs}"
echo "environment: ${environment}" 

...more code follow
```

From terminal I got the following error:

```
Missing environment parameter
```

I launch the following command from terminal.

```
./build.sh
```

Which parameter should I enter in my command?

Comment: You have to pass a parameter that will be used as a value of `environment` variable in the script: `environment=$1`

Comment: You have to actually provide an argument when you call the script. `./build.sh "some value"`.

Comment: The intended meaning of `environment` is not part of bash in general but specific to your script. We'd need to review later parts of the script where the variable is actually used to speculate at what values are intended.